# Using xmlProperty task with GANT

Tags: grails, ant, groovy, gant

I am writing a task with gant and I am getting struggled with the task xmlProperty. I have this example xml file:

```
<root>
    <properties>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </properties>
</root>
```

and when I do:

```
ant.xmlproperty(file:"myFile.xml")
println "${root.properties.foo}"
```

nothing is printed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure (hence the comment), but does `println ant.property( name:'someName', value:'${root.properties.foo}' )` work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works @tim_yates! Not sure why it is not working with double quotes, which I tried before. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, when you use double quotes, Groovy jumps in and tries to evaluate it as a Groovy String before passing it to antbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlproperty` loads the file in to Ant properties, not Groovy variables, so you need to access them via `project.properties` on the `AntBuilder` instance:

```groovy
println ant.project.properties.'root.properties.foo'
```